Using DSolve result with EllipticF
My goal is to find r[t] in expression 1 and then substitute r[t] into expression 2. However, the output of equation 1 appears, but it is an equatiopn with EllipticF Function . Is there a way to obtain the result of Expression 1 with a rule such as r[t]->__ with the help of WL? Or If not possible,could I have application of NDSolve fot this case?
Expression1
DSolve[-((G M )/r[t]^2) == -r[t] (c/2)^2 + r''[t], r[t], t]   (*How to get r[t]-> *)

Expression2
Integrate[c/r[t]^2, t]


Perhaps with some mathematical cleverness. The reason you didn't get a Rule is because Solve[] couldn't solve the equation symbolically, so the chances are not great.

It might help to add initial conditions.  Perhaps you could select your time origin so that r'[0]=0.  Perhaps you could denote r[0]=R.  You could add assumptions that parameters are positive and real, as appropriate.  You could try giving simple numerical values to all the parameters (e.g. 1 or 0, as appropriate) and see if you get a solution.  You have a polynomial root.  Perhaps you can ensure that this takes a real value?

Why are you using C[1] in your input ode?  This is used by Mathematica. Can you not choose different symbol? Or is there specific reason?

@Nasser Thank you for your comment, I have just replaced C[1] with c as different symbol for the constant. ※My goal is to get eclipse in the polar coordinate  by trying  expression1 to get r[t], then put it into expresion2 (=θ[t])

If you want to solve for a Kepler ellipse in polar coordinates, start with the constants of motion, angular momentum and negative total energy in  bound state
  DSolve[{L == m r[t]  \[Phi]'[t] , 
          m/2  r'[t]^2  + m/2 r[t]^2  \[Phi]'[t]^2 - (G m M)/r[t] == -W}, 
         {r, \[Phi]}, t]

If you only are looking for  the equation of the ellipse, eliminate $t,\dot \phi$ by the first equation and use the chain rule to replace $r'[t]$ by $r'[\phi]$
$$\frac{1}{2}\  m \ r'[t]^2+\frac{1}{2}\ m \  r[t]^2 \phi '[t]^2-\frac{G \ m\ M}{r[t]}\ =  -m\ W$$
with
$$ \phi'[t] = \frac{L}{ r[t]^2} \ ,\quad r'[t] = r'[\phi] \ \phi '[t] \ , \quad r[t]\to r[\phi]$$
  1/r[\phi]/.
  DSolve[L^2/(2 m)-(m M)/r[\phi]+(L^2 (r'[\phi])^2)/(2 m r[\phi]^2)==-W,
      r[\phi],\phi][[-1]]//
   FullSimplify

$$\frac{1}{r(t)} \ = \ \frac{L^2+2 m W}{m^2 M \left(1+\cos \left(\frac{(\phi +c_1 L) \sqrt{L^2+2 m W}}{L}\right)\right)}$$
